# Excel Show Data Based on user Choice

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

Excel 2007: I get my data from Access tables the Excel sheet is called "Data". My Excel report cells are populated by linking to those data cells(=Data!A1) and some report cells have simple code.  But my question is this; my report needs to specify one record. Example: Data record 1: Name=Joe, Birth=7/29/62, Country=USA: record 2: Name=Sam, Birth=4/13/74, Country=China...  How do we control the report display to a specific record?  If I add a DropDown or ListBox, how do we make only the records for the name picked show in the report. Is there a way to put the code behind the listbox, or should I scrap the list and create a macro, what is the best way for a user to pick the data to be displayed on the report?  Suggestions please...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two approaches I would use.

When you embed a query object in Excel (which is, I assume, how you are fetching the data from Access) you have the ability to edit that query in the little Query Editor tool. 
You can add criteria to that query in this tool - there's a filter icon, you select let's say the Name column, and then type "Sam" in the box below, and that will produce a SQL statement that now includes "Where Name = 'Same'" at the end.

However, that's not that helpful for reporting, since most likely we want the name to be a parameter passed in from the Excel sheet itself. If in the criteria box, you type "[enter name]" instead of "Sam", the square brackets tell the Query tool that this is a user supplied parameter. When you run the query from the tool now you get a pop up box asking you each time for the name.

Now when you exit the query tool and return to Excel, you can edit the Query Parameters for that embedded query object. The parameter you made (name) is there, and it can either take on a static value, prompt the user, or take the contents of a cell. You can even set a flag to refresh the query when the cell contents change.

The other approach goes a little further and manipulates the query object in some VBA code. If you need to do some heavier lifting, or other logic, for example, and you don't want to deal with writing it all out as spreadsheet formulas. An easy way to do that is to drop in a button on the report sheet and have the VBA code start on that button's click event.

Comment: The Data sort has to be done in Excel by the end user, which is what your last paragraph describes. I am now using one sheet for both report and data ("data in A1:H35" and "data in Z1:AF200")...

Comment: continued: I have a dropdown to show only the unique names. With your suggestion of a Button's click event, could you please help me fix this if statement to populate the specific data, then I can map the report to those cells: Private Sub RunName_Click() =IF(ButtonName <> “ “ Then display data only for that name) End Sub... Maybe if data was on a separate sheet it would be easier ??

Comment: Not sure I follow your follow on question. I have, in the past, made workbooks with multiple query objects. These can be refreshed from the VBA side; so you might have a sheet that runs the query to get the list of names refresh when the workbook opens, and fill out a range that is then used as the pick list in a drop down, and then have a second query that fires on the result of that selection.